# MySQL nested set sub category calculation slow

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, nested

I have a table for categories with a nested set model. Each row should contain its count of sub-categories and how much articles are in those or '0' if there aren't any.

I've searched arround and found two possible solutions but nothing of them works:
[MySQL & nested set: slow JOIN (not using index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716788/mysql-nested-set-slow-join-not-using-index)
[Why isn't MySQL using any of these possible keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719392/why-isnt-mysql-using-any-of-these-possible-keys)

Create Table categories:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `GROUP_ID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `GROUP_NAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `PARENT_ID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `TYPE` enum('root','node','leaf') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'node',
  `LEVEL` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `GROUP_ORDER` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `GROUP_DESCRIPTION` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `total_articles` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_cats` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lft` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rgt` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`GROUP_ID`),
  KEY `PARENT_ID` (`PARENT_ID`),
  KEY `lft` (`lft`),
  KEY `rgt` (`rgt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`total_cats` is the amount of sub-categories in the rows tree.
The following query will do exactly what i want: all sub-category and article counts. **But it is very slow. It takes more than 80 seconds to perform on ~5000 categories and ~40000 articles.** The calculation of `total_articles` is already done by another script. (If there arent any articles, all rows should hold `0` for `total_articles`)

The Query:

```
SELECT a.GROUP_ID,a.PARENT_ID,COUNT(b.GROUP_ID) as total_cats,(
   SELECT SUM(c.total_articles)
   FROM categories c
   WHERE c.PARENT_ID = a.GROUP_ID) as total_articles
FROM categories as b
   INNER JOIN categories as a
     ON a.lft < b.lft AND a.rgt > b.rgt
GROUP BY a.GROUP_ID
```

It results in something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| GROUP_ID                                  | PARENT_ID                           | total_cats | total_articles |
+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| 69_69_1                                   | 69_69_0                             |       4252 |              0 |
| 69_69_Abfall__Wertstoffsammler___zubehoer | 69_69_NWEAB290h001                  |          5 |             20 |
| 69_69_Abisolierzangen                     | 69_69_NWAAA458h001                  |          4 |             56 |
| 69_69_Abzieher_2                          | 69_69_NWAAB944h001                  |         23 |            476 |
| 69_69_Abziehvorrichtung                   | 69_69_Abzieher_2                    |          3 |             18 |
| 69_69_Aexte                               | 69_69_NWEAA615h001                  |          6 |             45 |
| 69_69_Alarmgeraete_Melder                 | 69_69_Sicherungstechnik__Heimschutz |          3 |              4 |
| 69_69_Allgemeiner_Industriebedarf         | 69_69_Industrieausruestung          |          8 |             21 |
| 69_69_Allgemeines_Schweisszubehoer        | 69_69_NWEAB113h001                  |         27 |             97 |
| 69_69_Anker__Befestigungstechnik__1       | 69_69_Befestigungstechnik           |          5 |            163 |
```

The explain if it helps:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                          |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | b     | ALL  | lft,rgt       | NULL      | NULL    | NULL | 4253 | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | ALL  | lft,rgt       | NULL      | NULL    | NULL | 4253 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0xC) |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ref  | PARENT_ID     | PARENT_ID | 767     | func |    7 | NULL                                           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, it doesnt use the indexes. If i put `FORCE INDEX (lft,rgt)` next to the `JOIN` the query executes, but nothing changes. Also tried to add an index on both columns lft and right:

```
ALTER TABLE `categories` ADD INDEX `nestedset` (`lft`, `rgt`);
```

But that doesnt help at all. The query still is slow.

Interestingly: The query is pretty fast if the categories table is just filled with a small amount of rows e.g. 260. But if it reaches 1000+ it will become slower and slower.

Example data with ~4000 categories: http://pastebin.com/BsViwFM5 **its a big file!**
Thanks for any help and hints!

Comment: maybe better asked at dba.stackexchange?

Comment: maybe u are right, but others asked with similar situations so if anyone want to migrate it, feel free to do so =)

Comment: Incidentally, wherever the word INT appears, the number that follows it is fairly meaningless

Comment: so what should i use instead? Originally the lft and rgt columns was INTs, so i changed it to smallint so mysql doesnt have to use the full INT-scale

Comment: I would stick with INT throughout - but either way, I doubt it makes much difference to performance. Your choice of a VARCHAR id (for both group and parent) perhaps hinders performance very slightly, but probably not a lot.

Comment: I'll give it a try, unfortunately i have to go with varchars on GROUP_ID and PARENT_ID cause of dependencies :/ Or should i add "real" IDs and just use the actual GROUP_ID as text?

Comment: I would - but it's your design, not mine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the EXPLAIN for this look like?

```
SELECT a.GROUP_ID
     , a.PARENT_ID
     , COUNT(b.GROUP_ID) total_cats
     , c.total_articles
  FROM categories b
  JOIN categories a
    ON a.lft < b.lft 
   AND a.rgt > b.rgt
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT parent_id 
           , SUM(total_articles) total_articles
        FROM categories 
       GROUP 
          BY parent_id
     ) c
    ON c.parent_id = a.GROUP_ID
 GROUP 
    BY a.GROUP_ID
```

Comment: Your query is faster than mine but also runs for about 10 seconds. You can find the explain here: http://pastebin.com/ZH7cTCGn

Comment: I guess I'd try with a covering index on lft,rgt . I can't see that there's that much else you can do - but others might be able to help further

Comment: tested with adding an 2 column index nestedset like above. The explain still doesnt show to use this new key but the query was 1 second faster. Anyways thats a good improvement 80 > 10!

Comment: since there arnt any other solutions to "fix" this, yours is the best and provided an improvement =) Thanks!

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Did you remove the separate index on lft? I cannot understand why the query isn't using the lft-rgt index.

Comment: I tried it right now an removed the "standalone" index on lft and rgt. It just does not use the lft-rgt index, However without those two single indexes the query was even faster, it took just 5 sec, Great!

Comment: That sounds like caching to me. Asking a fresh question (referring back to this one) about why my query doesn't use that index may elicit further response.

Answer (score 0):

The right-left tree is a cute "textbook" technique.  But, as you are finding out, it does not scale for the 'real world'.

The `EXPLAIN` show that it scanning all of `b`, then for each such row, it is scanning all of `a`.  That's Order(N^2) -- 5000*5000 = 25 million operations.

Actually, this relatively new operation (`Range checked for each record (index map: 0xC)`) implies that it is not quite that bad.

The optimizer really can't do much better at finding 'betweenness' because one bit of missing info:  whether the ranges are overlapping.

Your task *may* be better achieved by switching to a hierarchical schema, and "walking" the tree, either in app code, or in a Stored Routine.

With MariaDB 10.2 or MySQL 8.0, you can write a "Recursive CTE" do walk the tree in a single, though complicated, query.

Comment: yeah i thought that its main "problem" is the betweenness. I already had a recursive function tested, done in php (parent->groups etc) but that was even slower. Maybe u could provide an example query please?

Comment: How could the ranges overlap !?!?